# How can I estimate the standard deviation

Tags: stock-analysis, statistics

How can I estimate the standard deviation from stock graph without calculates, just from the graph

Answer (score 2):

Look at adding a standard deviation indicator to your charts. If your chart provider doesn't have this indicator then chose a provider that does.

Comment: +1, yet the question has me curious if one can estimate with any level of accuracy from looking at a chart? Would the difference between a 10%STD and 20%STD be obvious?

Answer (score 1):

One third of the distance between the largest value and the smallest value can least accurately yet most quickly manually estimate the standard deviation.